# Core Bluetooth discover does not discover some devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have got 3 devices, 1 iPhone, 1 iPad, 1 macbook and using core bluetooth to discover the others.

iPad (peripheral)

iPhone (central)

macbook (central)

When the iPad/peripheral is advertising and the others are in central mode I can only discover it on the macbook. The iPhone never sees the advertising data. If I switch roles the same thing happens again. The iOS devices never see each other, only the macbook can see them. I am going crazy and don't know what else to do. **Any ideas?**

**BluetoothCentral.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothCentral: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    override init(){
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
    }
    
}

extension BluetoothCentral: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
          case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
          case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
          case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
          case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
          case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
          case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)

        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown")
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral)
        print("---------> \(peripheral.name)")
    }
}
```

**BluetoothPeripheral.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

let SERVICE_NAME = "card-iphone"

class BluetoothPeripheral: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var uuid:String = ""
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?
    
    required override init() {
          super.init()
       }

    func start(uuid: String){
        self.uuid = uuid
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
}

extension BluetoothPeripheral: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            if peripheral.isAdvertising {
                peripheral.stopAdvertising()
            }
            let advertisingData: [String : Any] = [
                CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: SERVICE_NAME
            ]
        
            self.peripheralManager?.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
        } else {
            print("handle other states")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't actually added a peripheral to your cbperipheral manager

Comment: I don't think that matters here. The macbook/central is able to discover the advertised data using the same centralManager code

Comment: I think it does matter, which is why I said it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices Same thing happens with Apple's example code that has a peripheral added to the manager

Comment: I took your code and added a service to the peripheral manager, mainly so I could scan for a specific service; If I didn't do that my central sees the numerous peripherals that are around and it is difficult to determine why it has discovered  given peripheral.  Have you tried the LightBlue app instead of your central code?

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunately LightBlue cannot discover my mobile devices too. On the other hand Android devices can successfully discover it

Comment: Once i added the service with a characteristic I definitely had no issue discovering devices whether the Mac was a central or one of two iPhones or an iPad Pro

Comment: Thanks for the help Paulw. Could you please share some code?

Comment: This is my Bluetooth.swift - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/6401dac685b2bac8f8b3b4385bc51841 I simply instantiate a peripheral or central in the didLoad